# Deleting Rows via Views in Native Dinamic SQL

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql

Am trying to delete rows via views in native dinamic sql using procedure and facing the erros showing in the below. Could someone help me?

cORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06512: at "USER1.DEL_WITH_VIEW", line 11
ORA-06512: at line 1

```
create or replace procedure del_with_view (my_tab_name2 user_tables.table_name%type,
                                         row_count number)
is 
temp_table user_tables.table_name%type;
sql_query varchar2(1000);
begin
temp_table:=dbms_assert.sql_object_name(my_tab_name2);
sql_query:= 'create or replace view my_view as (
select rowid from '||temp_table||' fetch first '||row_count||' rows only);
delete from '||temp_table||' where rowid in '||'(select rowid from my_view)';
execute immediate sql_query;
dbms_output.put_line(sql_query);
dbms_output.put_line(sql%rowcount||'row deleted');
end;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/EXECUTE-IMMEDIATE-statement.html#GUID-C3245A95-B85B-4280-A01F-12307B108DC8). The statement must be "String literal, string variable, or string expression that represents a SQL statement". The code you posted has 2 statements. Change the code to execute 2 statements.

This works:

```
create or replace procedure del_with_view (
   my_tab_name2 user_tables.table_name%type
  ,row_count    number
) is
   temp_table user_tables.table_name%type;
   sql_query  varchar2(1000);
   sql_query2 varchar2(1000);
begin
   temp_table := dbms_assert.sql_object_name(my_tab_name2);
   sql_query := 'create or replace view my_view (row_id) as (select rowid from '
                || temp_table
                || ' fetch first '
                || row_count
                || ' rows only)';
   sql_query2 := 'delete from '
                 || temp_table
                 || ' where rowid in '
                 || '(select row_id from my_view)';
   execute immediate sql_query;
   execute immediate sql_query2;
   dbms_output.put_line(sql%rowcount
                        || ' row deleted');
end;
```

```
begin
   del_with_view(
                my_tab_name2 => 'EMP'
               ,row_count => 4
   );
end;
/
4 row deleted


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Note I changed the view to have an explicit column name "row_id". This is because "rowid" is a reserved word and should not be used as column name and it will fail with this error:

```
ORA-00998: must name this expression with a column alias
ORA-06512: at "DEL_WITH_VIEW", line 19
ORA-06512: at line 2
00998. 00000 -  "must name this expression with a column alias"
```

Comment: create or replace procedure proc_for_deleting (tab_name user_tables.table_name%type,
                                        row_count number)
is
my_query varchar2(1000);
my_tab_name user_tables.table_name%type;
begin
my_tab_name:=dbms_assert.sql_object_name(tab_name);
my_query := 'delete from '||my_tab_name||' where rowid in '||'(select rowid from '||my_tab_name||' fetch first '||row_count||' rows only)';
dbms_output.put_line(my_query);
dbms_output.put_line(' ');

execute immediate my_query;
end;
/  i wrote it in single statement. But howit works cant get the difference exactly?

Comment: @MatinHuseynli What isn't working exactly? Please don't use comments for long code examples.

Comment: I am freshman here thats why, do not know how to use it in a proper way. The code i added to the comments with single statement works. Cant get the difference

Comment: The code you posted in the comment contains a single SQL delete statement. The code you posted originally contains 2 statements: a create view statement and a delete statement. The comment code works because in a single ```EXECUTE IMMEDIATE``` statement, you're executing a single SQL statement. Same as I'm doing in my solution.